# Php Logic statement synatx error due to comma

Tags: php

Can anyone help

```
<?php 
if(((count( $replies ) > 6) and 
(count( $replies ) <= 12)) and 
($replyNumber == '3','4','5'))
{ ?>
<execute code......>
<?php } ?>
```

Why due to use of comma (in replynumber as 3,4,5  is getting an error in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code have error in

```
($replyNumber == '3','4','5'))
```

and  it could be like

```
($replyNumber == '3' && $replyNumber == '4' && $replyNumber == '5'))
```

in your code

```
'and'
```

should be converted to
    `'&&'` as `'and'` is not allowed in php

and complete code be like

```
<?php 
 if(((count( $replies ) > 6) &&
  (count( $replies ) <= 12)) && 
  ($replyNumber == '3' && $replyNumber == '4' && $replyNumber == '5'))
{ ?>
<execute code......>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: i think there should be OR condition like :$replyNumber == '3' || $replyNumber == '4'

Comment: yes using Pritam solution with or condition works. Thanks both of you

Comment: @Ruchika .. I think you have to use `and` after where you count two values and before the $replyNumber. ??

Answer (score 2):

Change your code like this :

```
<?php 
$varArray = array('3','4','5');
if( ((count( $replies ) > 6) && (count( $replies ) <= 12)) && (in_array($replyNumber,$varArray)) )  { ?>
    <execute code......>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> **You Have an `syntax error, of comma's`**  and  (You Have To Used `or` for `$replyNumber` values   )

```
<?php

if( ((count($replies)>6) or (count($replies)<=12)) and $replyNumber=='3' or $replyNumber=='4' or $replyNumber=='5' )     
{

// your execute code here

}
?>
```

> **NOTE:**

- `or` & `||` are  `Or Logical Operators`

**Ex:**  `$x or $y`  **True if either $x or $y is true**

**Ex:**  `$x || $y`  **True if either $x or $y is true**

- `and` & `&&` are `And Logical Operators`

**Ex:**  `$x and $y`     **True if both $x and $y are true**

**Ex:**  `$x && $y`  **True if both $x and $y are true**